# How to modify each broker message for each receiver inside a channel individually in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-websocket, messagebroker

I'm sending a message to a channel but have to modify it for each client.

Anyone with experience on how to do that?

Comment: Modify what? The message or the channel? And what client: publisher or consumer?

Comment: like the header is stating: "modify each broker message". If I want to modify the message that is being received, then it's obviously the consumer.

Comment: OK. So how do you generate the message? How should it differ between clients?

Comment: I'm using MessagingTemplate to send payloads to a specific channel via: messagingTemplate.convertAndSend(channel, payload);

Comment: I have to modify the payload for each consumer before it's leaving the server-stack/websocket.

Comment: Then why don't you modify `payload`?

Comment: Because it's broadcasted as it is to all consumers. I have to add slight changes to the payload for EACH consumer. See question.

Comment: Nothing in your question talks about *broadcast*. Broadcasting differing messages makes no sens.

Comment: Channels are for broadcasts. And yes, in this case it seems to make no sense, but I have to do it that way, because otherwise I'm have to send every single message to a different channel and keep track of all available consumers which would be simply make even less sense. There must be simply a way to hook up to all outgoing messages. Will try to find a solution myself. Thank you

Comment: The publisher should not even be awary of the consumers. Also, you can of course send all messages about a single AMQP channel. Maybe not using Spring, but AMQP channels should be reused.

Comment: Now you answered your own concerns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go.

Spring offers interceptors for incoming and outgoing channels.
So simply add an interceptor and you're ready to catch every in- and outgoing message and do whatever you want to.

First your config:

```
...

@Autowired
private InboundMessagesChannelInterceptor inboundMessagesChannelInterceptor;

@Autowired
private OutboundMessagesChannelInterceptor outboundMessagesChannelInterceptor;

@Override
public void configureClientInboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(inboundMessagesChannelInterceptor);
}

@Override
public void configureClientOutboundChannel(ChannelRegistration registration) {
    registration.interceptors(outboundMessagesChannelInterceptor);
}

...
```

and your interceptor:

```
@Component
public class OutboundMessagesChannelInterceptor implements ChannelInterceptor {

    @Override
    public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
        // modify your message as needed
        return message;
    }

}
```

Thats it.